# Batches in python from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Actually I am having list of 500 elements such as

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5...500]
```

Now I want to create a batch of of 32 elements and store in nested list where the main list contains nested list of 32-32 elements and last nested list contains 20 elements such as:

```
final_list = [[1,2,3,..,32],[33,34,35,..,64],..,[480,481,482,..500]]
```

I was trying with append from loop but not having exact idea how to do so.

```
final_list = []
for itr in range(0,500,32):
    final_list.append(l[0:itr])
```

Tried with various method but not able to find the correct logic.
Any help would be great and thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a list comprehension:

```
final_list = [my_list[x:x+32] for x in range(0, len(my_list), 32)]
```

---

For example,

```
my_list = list(range(0, 500))
batch_size = 32
final_list = [my_list[n:n+batch_size] for n in range(0, len(my_list), batch_size)]
```

and the final output would be

```
[
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 
  [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63],
...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the starting index as you move along in the `for` loop:

```
final_list = []
offset = 32
for itr in range(0, len(l), offset):
    final_list.append(l[itr:itr+offset])
print(final_list)
```